# Ingresar en SQL SERVER fechas nulas

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

vengo a solicitar vuestra ayuda para intertar una solución al siguiente tema.
En un formulario en C# tengo seis DateTimepickers para ingresar las fechas de unas pagos divididos hasta un maximo de seis veces. El problema es cuando, por ejemplo, solo tengo que pagar tres parcelas, tambiem me ingresa las fechas de las otras tres restantes.

¿Como puedo hacer para que en la base de datos de Sql Server se ingrese como "NULL", osea que no se ingrese nada?

Trabajo en n capas y los insert se hacen por parámetros.

Desde ya agradezco vuestro tiempo y dedicación.

Comment: podes usar una fecha default que represente el NULL y/o esconder un textbox que se actualiza al evento onchange del datepicker, si el textbox está vacío es que no se usó el datepicker

Comment: Por favor, añade el código relevante

Answer (score 3):

Si los datos son variables no deberias definido como columnas, eso es a causa de un pesimo diseño de la tabla, podrias haber definir filas.

Una fila para cada pago, para esto agregas una columna de `nro cuota` o si quieres la fecha de pago. Si lo diseñas de esta forma no necesitas indicar ningun null porque  varias los insert que realizas, si son 6 pagos tendras 6 registros si son 3 seran 3 registros.

```
Pagos (tabla)
  PagoId  PK
  NroCuota
  Fecha
  Monto
```

---

Ahora si quieres continuar con tu diseño deberias asignar el valor `DBNull.Value` al parametro para indicar que es null su valor

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", DBNull.Value);
```

Por supuesto el campo en la db debe permiti null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si el problema es el control `DateTimePicker` que no permite seleccionar un valor sin definir existen alternativas de diseño.

- Una podria ser adicionar un `checkbox` al costado del datetimepicker indicando si se define el valor o si no se indica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede crear un `user control` para agrupar esta funcionalidad. La idea es que si se marca el checkbox no tomas la seleccion del datepicker, sino que envias `DBNull.Value` como parametro

- Otra opcion seria usar un componente como ser

[Yet Another Nullable DateTimePicker Control](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c9645/Yet-Another-Nullable-DateTimePicker-Control.htm)

El cual en la propia seleccion tiene la opcion de no seleccionar una fecha

Comment: Leandro,Seguramente no supe explicar bien lo que pretendo hacer.La BBDD consta de un campo con el nombre de la persona a pagar y seis campos con Fecha_primera, Fecha_segunda, Fecha_tercera y así hasta seis Como comenté el problema es que los DateTimepickers siempre envían una fecha por defecto y al recuperar los datos, siempre parece que se haya dividido en seis veces. El insert se envía de una sola vez con todos los parámetros.Sitienes algún ejemplo ya sea de construcción de la BBDD o alguna sugerencia de cambiar los controles del formulario por otros, te lo agradecería, 
Gracias, Joaquim

Comment: Te expliaste perfecto, es justamente estos campos Fecha_xx los que esta incorrectos, no deberian ser campos, deberian ser registros

Comment: edite la respueta, veras que menciono controles para no tener que seleccionar una fecha

Comment: Sólo para apoyar el comentario de @LeandroTuttini en relación al diseño. Lo mejor sería agregar una tabla relacionada con las fechas de los pagos y no tener un campo en la tabla principal para cada uno.

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios, voy a buscar como hacer esta forma de ingresar por separado los datos, no hago la menor idea de como construir esta tabla, ademas no soy nada bueno ed BBDDy tengo poca (casi nula) experiencia en programación.

Comment: Hola de nuevo,
Estoy atascado, he hecho una tabla con un solo campo “Fecha_pago” del tipo ‘DateTime’, pero no consigo pasarle los parámetros y la fecha correcta, siempre me ingresa un solo registro y con fecha “0001-01-01”. Realmente no sé lo que estoy haciendo mal, debe ser por las ‘n’ capas, no sé cómo pasar los datos y me imagino que al final debe ir un’ foreach’ para recorrer el ‘DataTable’ para ingresar un dato por cada parámetro que corresponda a un registro. Si podéis echarme una mano, no pido la respuesta total, si es posible una orientación, para empezar a andar
Gracias, Joaquim

Comment: En el planteo que realizas mezclas muchas cosas, si programas en capas que tiene que ver un datatable, no se usa, deberias definir class con propiedades. Ademas no se como asignas los parametros del command, si es un datetime valido deberia usas ese como valor al insertar. Si se ingresa un solo registro quiere decir que no estas realizando un INSERT sino un UPDATE, sino no se explica, salvo que al tener una lista no lo estes iterando correctamente.

Comment: después de leer tu comentario, me puse a revisar todo el código de la aplicación, te comento que es una adaptación de un ejemplo que encontré en internet.
Tenias razón, el problema estaba en una lista que envía los datos a los parámetros para después almacenarlos en la tabla de SqlSever, y no estaba iterando correctamente.
Quiero agradecer a todos vuestro esfuerzo y especialmente a ti Leandro, por enseñar a los principiantes, aunque mis neuronas ya están un poco oxidadas (65 años) y les cuesta asimilar.
Hasta la proxima ocasión, un abrazo, Joaquim

Comment: @JoaquimVolart la mejor manera de agradecer es votar positivamente y en su caso, aceptar la respuesta que te haya ayudado. Un saludo